# please any one can solve this error message for me: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO memokereya.random (
    number, 
    serial, 
    type
    )
SELECT 
    number,
    serial,
    type,
    COUNT(serial)
    FROM 
    test.random
   GROUP BY number,serial,type
HAVING COUNT(serial) > 1;
```

Comment: What's to solve? you are attempting to force 4 columns into 3, And insert select won't generate columns for you.

Answer (score 0):

remove `COUNT(serial)` from select list

```
INSERT INTO memokereya.random (
    number, 
    serial, 
    type
    )
SELECT 
    number,
    serial,
    type
    FROM 
    test.random
   GROUP BY number,serial,type
HAVING COUNT(serial) > 1
```